# A word for someone who is easily driven by anyone for anything, but he's not foolish/innocent

Tags: word-request, word-usage

Consider Mike for this.

I want a term that describes Mike, who is very easily 'convinceable'. But, Mike is not foolish or innocent. In other words, anybody able to fog a mirror can go, convince, and fulfill their wish.

Simplest example is...a salesperson with a bogus product going to Mike; it's easy for him to convince Mike. Mike purchases product without any hassle **or** a contractor going to Mike, convincing him for a fraudulent scheme project without much efforts.

What do we call Mike? A word for a person who can be convinced easily; **but** please mind it, he's not foolish or innocent. He's just easily convinceable.

My homework: I tried OneLook Reverse but could not get the term :(

Comment: Gullible is first that springs to mind - or maybe credulous

Comment: @Tetsujin ahhh...gullible is **so** close! :) thanks

Comment: A fool and his money are soon parted.

Comment: Naive is another word that springs to mind.

Comment: Your question is analogous to "He's about 70 kilos overweight but he's not obese."-- hence the downvote.

Comment: Not a single word, but I think it's worth a mention. "[To be easily led](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lead_1)" (First of the phrases) i.e. "Mike is easily led".

Comment: Also not a single word... "Mike was easily fooled."

Comment: Credulous? (Or overcredulous?) Impressionable? Unwary? Easily taken in?

Comment: @TRomano Rather than provide vague quotations / analogies, please be more direct in helping the Questioner by stating what you think the issue is and why. Otherwise, your comment may  sound sarcastic and your point can be lost.  As I see it, you probably take issue with OP's use of "foolish" as in, "One who is gullible **is foolish**." It may be a definition of *foolish* that the OP isn't thinking about.

Comment: credulous, btw, was a late thought - I didn't want to just give a one-word comment… Personally, I think the word credulous will end up in the archaic dump-bin before too long, eventually becoming one of those words for which there is no longer a 'positive' - like 'kempt' or 'ept' ;)

Comment: @TRomano rethink! Hadn't I mention 'innocent' in my question, the very first **answer** could have been 'Call Mike an innocent person'. :) But +1 for the word 'naive' ;)

Comment: @JMB that's what **exactly** I have been using!

Answer (score 1):

**Gullible** is good IMO.

From http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/gullible:  easily fooled or cheated, especially : quick to believe something that is not true.  *I'm not gullible enough to believe something that outrageous.*  *They sell overpriced souvenirs to gullible tourists.*

**Credulous** also fits, but from my experience/cultural-exposure, many people have told me they were (or someone else was) gullible, but I don't recall anyone describing someone as *credulous*.  Strange.

Wikipedia has a comparison under [gullibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullibility):

- ***Gullibility*** is a failure of social intelligence in which a person is easily tricked or manipulated into an ill-advised course of action. It is closely related to **credulity**, which is the tendency to believe unlikely propositions that are unsupported by evidence.

There is also some comparison (and interesting discussion) of the terms in wikipedia's [credulity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credulity) though (IMO) the definitions given are not as precise as the various references suggest.

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gullible%2C+credulous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgullible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccredulous%3B%2Cc0) is interesting, showing that credulous has declined in the 20th century.  This [COCA report](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=37907336) shows gullible is more common now.

Comment: Credulous to me tends to imply naïveté more strongly than gullible, and is more often associated with a group while gullible is more often associated with an individual. Anyone could be gullible in a particular situation, but in my experience credulous is more related to being unsophisticated in general. _"Oh I can't believe I was so gullible when I talked to that salesperson last week."_ versus _"The salesperson took advantage of the credulous populations of small towns throughout the state."_

Comment: @ColleenV A quick look at some COCA collacates and examples doesn't seem to support that distinction..

Comment: I don't think I articulated it well, and I do think you're right (obviously) about credulous being more rare. To me gullible describes individuals most often and credulous is used more often with groups or things, like "credulous stares" or "a credulous account of an event" or "credulous children". It's perfectly fine to say "he was credulous" but I would probably choose "he was gullible".

Comment: Yes, this one is quite close to what I want. +1 :)

Answer (score -1):

"Influenceable" or "susceptible" might work for that.

Edit:

It seems my answer was downvoted because I didn't include the definitions of the words. I didn't think posting the definitions of these was necessary, but anyway, here they are:

> [influenceable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/influenceable) (comparative more influenceable, superlative most
> influenceable) - Adjective
>
> 1. Capable of being influenced.

and

> [susceptible](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/susceptible) (comparative more susceptible, superlative most
> susceptible)
>
> 1. likely to be affected by something
>
>    ```
>    He was susceptible to minor ailments.
>    ```
> 2. easily influenced or tricked; credulous
>    (medicine) especially sensitive, especially to a stimulus
> 3. that, when subjected to a specific operation, will yield a specific result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community done. Let me know if it's ok now.